# Why do I get an error using a ternary operator inside a hash literal?

Tags: ruby

Doing something like below produces an error.

```
x = ""
h = {:a => x==nil?"":x}
```

Error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
h = {:a => x==nil?"":x}
```

Is it not possible to use the ternary operator in a hash literal definition?

Comment: If `x` is a string unless it is `nil`, then it can be better written as `h = {a: x.to_s}`.

Comment: `?"` is a valid expression, so how is Ruby supposed to know what you mean when you don't have a space?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Define the array one way or other, depending on the value of `x` at parse time? Or return a different value for the `:a` key at run-time depending on `x`?

Comment: Instead of `x == nil? "":x`, which is a syntax error, use `x || ''`.

Comment: @vgoff that was it. Needed a space so Ruby would know the question mark is for the ternary operator,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem in using the ternary operator in a hash literal definition.

In `x==nil?` the interpreter is considering the `?` along with `nil` as a call to the `nil?` method. So what would be the rest of the ternary operator is effectively a syntax error, since you don't really have a well formed operator because the `?` is not part of it.

What you should have entered, by using proper spacing, is:

```
h = {:a => x == nil ? "" : x}
```

Which can be better expressed as:

```
h = {:a => x.nil? ? "" : x}
```

If `false` is not a valid value for `x` you can also use the form `h = {:a => x || ""}` as suggested by [@Gareth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31582/gareth)

Also, if `x` is supposed to always be a `string`, you can use the form `h = {a: x.to_s}` as suggested by [@sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314166/sawa)

Comment: if `x` will never be the value `false` then `h = {:a => x || ""}` will also work with that variety of Hash syntax, in a terser form

Comment: @Gareth Even better: my comment to the question

Answer (score 4):

Take care of the space. Ruby will treat `nil?` as a method call. This works:

```
h = {:a => x==nil ? "" : x }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also (*gasp*) use parentheses, like so:

```
h = {:a => (x == nil)?"":x}
```

But you should really add spacing or use the `Object#nil?` method in this case anyway.